# How to save in excel cell slicer selection (multiple selections)?

Tags: excel, slicers

I have the below formula that works when there's a single slicer selection:

```
=CUBERANKEDMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel",CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel",Slicer_indication.indication_name1,"Test"),ROW(A1))
```

However, I need a similar formula that stores not only 1 selection, but multiple. Something that would give a similar result as: **Selection1, Selection2**.

I have been searching like crazy, but I can't seem to find a suitable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might need it:

```
=CUBERANKEDMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel",CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel",SLICER NAME,"Test"),ROW(A1))
```